# convert spacy hash back to string - after using .vocab

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I have the following code:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
word = nlp.vocab["world"]
final_synonym = ['universe','existence','creation','cosmos','macrocosm','domain','reality','earth','globe','populace','public','earthly_concern','human_race','humanity','humankind','human_beings','humans','mankind','man','global','planetary']
```

And I want to create a dictionary which stores the similarity between the word and every single element within final_synonym.

```
spacy_results = []
for i in range(len(final_synonym)):
    final_synonym[i] = nlp.vocab[final_synonym[i]]
    spacy_similarity = word.similarity(final_synonym[i])
    spacy_results.append(spacy_similarity)
```

Now if i create the dictionary:

```
res = {}
for key in final_synonym:
    for value in spacy_results:
        res[key] = value
        spacy_results.remove(value)
        break
```

Everything is fine, but the list final_synonym now contains the spacy hash of each element instead of the string. How can I convert the spacy hash back into the string it used to be?

My result is:

```
{<spacy.lexeme.Lexeme at 0x24fc0b06b00>: 0.6718395948410034,
 <spacy.lexeme.Lexeme at 0x24fc0b06600>: 0.4913380742073059,
 <spacy.lexeme.Lexeme at 0x24fc0ad3e40>: 0.3789522051811218,
 <spacy.lexeme.Lexeme at 0x24fc0b06840>: 0.4318424463272095,
 <spacy.lexeme.Lexeme at 0x24fc0b06cc0>: 0.3014813959598541,
 <spacy.lexeme.Lexeme at 0x24fc0ad1f00>: 0.23181180655956268,
 <spacy.lexeme.Lexeme at 0x24fc0ad1a80>: 0.5879489183425903,
 <spacy.lexeme.Lexeme at 0x24fc0ad1dc0>: 0.49156078696250916,
 <spacy.lexeme.Lexeme at 0x24fc0ad1e40>: 0.7273148894309998,
 <spacy.lexeme.Lexeme at 0x24fc0b03d40>: 0.4184108078479767,
 <spacy.lexeme.Lexeme at 0x24fc0ad1580>: 0.31901150941848755,
 <spacy.lexeme.Lexeme at 0x24fc0ad1900>: 0.0,
 <spacy.lexeme.Lexeme at 0x24fc0b00140>: 0.0,
 <spacy.lexeme.Lexeme at 0x24fc0aeee00>: 0.6186776161193848,
 <spacy.lexeme.Lexeme at 0x24fc0ad1cc0>: 0.6014578938484192,
 <spacy.lexeme.Lexeme at 0x24fc0ad1740>: 0.0,
 <spacy.lexeme.Lexeme at 0x24fc0ad1380>: 0.49049633741378784,
 <spacy.lexeme.Lexeme at 0x24fc0ad1980>: 0.5243041515350342,
 <spacy.lexeme.Lexeme at 0x24fc0ad1680>: 0.25401803851127625,
 <spacy.lexeme.Lexeme at 0x24fc0ad1480>: 0.5530120730400085,
 <spacy.lexeme.Lexeme at 0x24fc0ad12c0>: 0.42649978399276733}
```

Answer (score 0):

The vocab (or, more precisely, the StringStore it uses) works with either string-to-hash or hash-to-string conversions, so you can do `nlp.vocab.strings[hash]` to get the string. Note that if you supply a hash for a string the Vocab has not seen, you will get an error. You can read more about this [in the dev docs](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/extra/DEVELOPER_DOCS/StringStore-Vocab.md).

That said, is there a reason you don't just use string keys in your dictionary? It looks like you can avoid this entirely just by not using the first line inside your for loop.